# Scope not working in ActiveAdmin ROR

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, activeadmin

To allow me to quickly filter records in ActiveAdmin i've defined scopes on my model. I have "shipped" and "unshipped" scopes as below. For some reason the "Shipped" scope is working as expected and shows the number of shipped items but the "Unshipped" scope doesn't do anything, it doesn't seem to know what is unshipped. It seems that i have to check and then uncheck "Shipped" checkbox in order for it to know that it's unshipped??

ORDER MODEL

```
class Order < ActiveRecord::Base

    scope :shipped, where(:shipped => true)
    scope :unshipped, where(:shipped => false)

end
```

ADMIN ORDER MODEL

```
ActiveAdmin.register Order do

    scope :all, :default => true
    scope :shipped
    scope :unshipped

index do
    selectable_column
    column "Status", :sortable => :shipped do |s|
      status_tag((s.shipped? ? "Shipped" : "Unshipped"), (s.shipped? ? :ok : :warning))
    end
end
end
```

Can anyone see what the problem is?
Many Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Realised that `shipped` was not by default set to false so fixed the issue by doing so in the Orders table.

Comment: Yes booleans should always have a default otherwise they aren't really booleans.  But you should still be using a lambda in that scope.

Answer (score 0):

Is that the actual code from your model?

It should be:

```
scope :shipped, -> { where(shipped: true) }
scope :unshipped, -> { where(shipped: false) }
```

Comment: yeah, i've tried the way you suggest before and that has the exact same result arghh

Comment: You might try changing the name of your 'shipped' scope to something that isn't already an attribute (or otherwise defined on the model).

Comment: unfortunately, no luck :/

Comment: Does the Unshipped button appear with the index?  If so, what do you see in the log when it's clicked?

Comment: Yep, it does appear. `Parameters: {"scope"=>"unshipped"}
  AdminUser Load (0.2ms)  SELECT "admin_users".* FROM "admin_users" WHERE "admin_users"."id" = 1 ORDER BY "admin_users"."id" ASC LIMIT 1
   (0.2ms)  SELECT COUNT(*) FROM "orders"
   (0.1ms)  SELECT COUNT(*) FROM "orders" WHERE "orders"."shipped" = 'f'
   (0.2ms)  SELECT COUNT(*) FROM "orders" WHERE "orders"."shipped" = 't'
   (0.3ms)  SELECT COUNT(count_column) FROM (SELECT 1 AS count_column FROM "orders" WHERE "orders"."shipped" = 'f' LIMIT 30 OFFSET 0) subquery_for_count`

Comment: it seems that the model doesn't know that shipped is false by default